# Чтение данных из памяти компьютера напрямую

Tags: c++, память, dma

Решил поэкспериментировать с прямым чтением из памяти компьютера, устройств/контроллеров материнской платы, а именно CMOS (0x00000070)

Пытался прочитать данные в лоб:

```
int* pointer = (int*)0x00000070;
int a = *pointer; //0xC0000005
```

На что винда мне показала фигу 0xC0000005, мол это не твоя память.

Нагуглил функции inp и outp для чтения записи соответственно:

```
#include <conio.h>
unsigned int port;
int inp(port);
//main
int value = 0;
value = inp(0x70); //E0109
```

Тут мне уже сама Visual Studio до компиляции показала фигу и сказала: E0109 выражение перед скобками вероятного вызова должно иметь тип функции (pointer-to-)

Ищу дальше, нашёл inport, казалось бы что может быть роднее DOS функции:

```
#include <dos.h>
int inport(int portid);
//main
int value = 0;
value = inport(0x70); //LNK2019
```

И при компиляции Visual Studio говорит что нету inport ни в dos.h, ни по цепочке что тянет dos.h ...

Про теорию с кольцами защиты винды, реальным и виртуальным рижимом как бы в курсе, что такие вот трюки запрещены из-за безопасности. И для подобных фокусов сделаны WinAPI функции, но цель не сделать конкретно типовое действие, а именно иметь метод прямого доступа. Ведь есть утилиты, которые как-то имеют прямой доступ к железякам, например те-же самые утилиты производителей железа (мат.плат, hdd/ssd, итд...) и порой без установки фирменных драйверов, да те же вирусы, которые прячутся вне процессов (но цель не в этом), а для этого, если не ошибаюсь, нужен прямой доступ к физической памяти.

Поэтому может можно как-нибудь повысить приоритет процесса, чтобы он имел доступ выше кольца защиты, отведённому пользователю? Или есть проверенные и обкатанные функции для такой работы с памятью? Или может просто я, со своими скудными знаниями C++ заблудился в 3х соснах и у меня примитивная ошибка!?

Comment: Это сложная тема, нужно выйти из защищённого режима. почитайте как : [Переключение процессора из защищенного режима в реальный.](http://al-tm.ru/stati/stati-po-mat.-obespecheniyu/intel-.1)

Comment: @AlexGlebe разве может user-space процесс переключать режим процессора, пусть и в винде?

Comment: Думаю, в многозадачной операционной системе нельзя читать физическую память, не будучи ядром системы/драйвером. Собственно, вся концепция многозадачной ОС — про то, чтобы программы не могли лазить куда им вздумается.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev задумка про то чтобы не могли лазать куда вздумается - понятна, но тем не менее некоторые утилиты это делают, причём без драйверов.

Comment: @AlexGlebe с программами, которые меняют режим - сталкивался. Но есть 2 вопроса: можно ли перевести туда-обратно быстро и незаметно и что будет если будет во время выполнения ошибка, процессор останется в реальном режиме?

Comment: Если бы так просто можно было взять и повысить себе приоритет и безнаказанно читать чужую память, то куча зловредов это делало. Даже не каждому драйверу можно брать и просто так читать память напрямую.  Всякие программы, которые работают с железом обычно используют специализированное апи, очень часто сильно проприетарное. А некоторые специально перезагружают комп и погружаются как маленький образ линукса/доса, что бы иметь достаточно доступа (например, к прошивке BIOS). Если хочется именно читать всю память, лучше открыть статьи, как делать свои операционные системы и начать пробовать по ним.

Comment: Драйвер надо пилить на такое, у него доступа хватит. Но это сложно и пользователь врятли сможет его запустить.

Comment: @KoVadim но ведь в винде есть API функции для работы с чужой памятью ``ReadProcessMemory`` И утилиты для железа читают как-то данные из железа...

Comment: Тут на самом деле проблема на проблеме. Во первых, windows виртуализирует всю память и возникает вопрос - а чью именно читать? Своего процесса или чужого. Сам Биос в винде давно копируется в оперативную память и подменяется (так быстрее оказалось, называется shadowing). Но часто и биоса нет - есть uefi. Но вот нашлась вот такая функция https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemfirmwaretable - может это что то поможет.   А в целом, какая задача решается? побаловаться? просто почитать байтики?

Comment: @KoVadim не то, что побаловаться, скорее поэкспериментировать, если всё будет успешно - накидать для себя утилиту, которая будет хотя-бы частично мониторить параметры биоса без входа в сам биос. Для личных целей, чисто даже под свою материнку - это было бы крайне полезно. (под биос имею ввиду cmos, acpi, итд...)

Comment: Частный ответ (про почитать биосы, но не про винду; впрочем, меткам и заголовку вопроса вполне удовлетворяет): физическую память можно читать-писать через /dev/mem; [порты можно читать-писать через /dev/port или напрямую](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/IO-Port-Programming.pdf). Естественно, нужны привилегии, да и с ними это возможно не на всех конфигурациях ядра.